# How to keep playing full screen video from WebView after rotation on Android

Tags: android, rotation, android-webview, android-lifecycle, android-video-player

When the user clicks the full screen button on a video in a WebView, WebChromeClient calls [onShowCustomView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onShowCustomView(android.view.View,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback)) with the custom video view.  I use this callback to add the view to the fragment and display it full screen.

However, when I rotate the device, the activity is destroyed (as expected) along with the custom video view.

How can I make the WebView show the custom video view after rotation (without losing the current state of the video, e.g. playing/paused and offset)?  After calling restoreState with the WebView's saved instance state, it does not invoke WebChromeClient's onShowCustomView callback and seems to have no memory that the user was watching a video.  Even if I were to somehow save the video, it would no longer be connected to the WebView, and clicking the button to exit full screen would no longer trigger WebChromeClient's onHideCustomView callback.

Comment: For something like this, it might be better to opt out of the destroy-recreate cycle for orientation changes, via `android:configChanges` in the `<activity>` element in the manifest. You would need to adjust your layout manually for the new orientation, but it would keep the original `WebView` widget intact and not interrupt your playback.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I suppose that might be the simplest solution if it only affects the one activity.  Is there really no way to do this without opting out of the standard Android lifecycle?

Comment: I have no idea if there is a way to handle this without the opt-out. But if the video is on the Internet, I fear that the UX will be sub-par (e.g., rebuffering), even if you can find a solution to your specific concern.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried the 'orientation' configChanges method, but this resulted in another problem (which I posted as a new question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70611677/android-webview-video-custom-view-content-is-off-center-after-rotation -- Any thoughts?  Thank you.