# Android WebView video custom view content is off center after rotation

Tags: android, rotation, android-webview, android-lifecycle, android-video-player

When the user clicks the full screen button on a video in a WebView, WebChromeClient calls [onShowCustomView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onShowCustomView(android.view.View,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback)) with the custom video view. I use this callback to add the view to a fragment and display it full screen.

In a [comment on a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600974/how-to-keep-playing-full-screen-video-from-webview-after-rotation-on-android), it was suggested that I include 'orientation' in the android:configChanges element.  As far as I can tell, it is not possible to continue playback using standard Android destroy-recreate activity lifecycle.

However, after rotation, the custom video view provided by WebChromeClient appears to still be full screen, but the actual video player inside it is not positioned correctly (jammed into a corner):

[image]

Is there some way to force Android to relayout the video, perhaps in onConfigurationChanged?

Comment: This is one where a [mcve] might have helped.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not.